# Setting the textbox to read only on submit

Tags: javascript

Can anyone suggest me a javascript function to set the text box to readonly on pressing the submit button. So that the contents cannot be modified.

Comment: Just to clarify on the "cannot be modified" statement... _Anything_ client-side can be modified.  A savvy user can still enable the text box, enter a value in it, even manually include that value in a POST to the server.  If your intent is to use JavaScript for security, re-evaluate your approach.  Client-side form manipulation is for user experience, _server-side_ validation is required for security.

Answer (score 2):

To disable an `input` you'll want to set its `disabled` attribute.  If you can use jQuery then something like this would be what you're looking for:

```
$('#idOfYourInput').attr('disabled', true);
```

If jQuery isn't an option, then you'll want to use the `setAttribute` function.  Take a look at [the MDN documentation for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute).  Something like this:

```
var d = document.getElementById('idOfYourInput'); 
d.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
```

(Both of these code samples assume that you're identifying your `input` by its `id` attribute.  If that's not the case, these would need to change.  The jQuery one would be trivial to change, you'd just need to update your selector to identify the target attribute.  The latter code sample would need to use some other DOM navigation/selection functions to find your `input` element.)

You'd want to include this within the handler for your submit button.  Understand, however, that this will only matter on the current context of the page.  So I'm *assuming* your submit button is being used to perform a submit via AJAX and not actually POST the whole page, correct?  Because if you're POSTing the whole page then, when the page refreshes, you'll be on an entirely new page context.  (Which means any code associated with a button click event will not yet have run.)

Comment: The situation is that I have a form that is filled out and then when it is submitted I leave the form where it is but disable the input fields so it can't be changed. So the user can continue to see what they have submitted.

Comment: @user1403763: If you're rendering an entirely new page, why present it as form elements if the user isn't supposed to edit them?  Form elements exist for the purpose of editing data.  If the user should only see the data, then show it to them without a form.  You can style it to look very similar to the form, if that's a requirement of the user experience.  But put the data in non-editable things like `span` tags.

Comment: Guess my explanation was not proper.I have a financial year table.which has certain text fields for the user to enter(ie the target details).User is given login.When the user logs in, he can enter the data(not complusorily all).Whatever details entered by the user shwould get saved on submit button.When the user logs in back the already filled text box should be disabled so that the user can continue entering the details in the other fields.

Comment: @user1403763: That doesn't change the approach, though.  If a user shouldn't be able to edit a particular piece of data, then that data shouldn't be presented to them in a form field.  It should just be displayed as data.  If you insist on displaying it in a form field, you can tell the browser to prevent editing with the approach in my answer, but understand that the user can change that setting if they are so inclined. You'd probably want to do it on the initial page load instead of the submit button (or do it server-side before rendering the page). You'll still want to validate server-side.